# Check if user still has the app connected to their SoundCloud account?

Tags: oauth, soundcloud

When a user connects to my SoundCloud web app and then disconnects it through their SoundCloud settings, my app stops working and returns a 401 error:

> Error Code 500
>
> The requested URL responded with HTTP code 401.

I'm using the SoundCloud PHP library.

Currently on connecting I save the user's Soundcloud User ID to a session and database, and I save the oauth token and secret to a database.

What happens is when the user hits Connect on my website after disconnecting the app from their SoundCloud settings is the following:

Code checks the user's SoundCloud ID and tries to authenticate using the OAuth credentials saved to the database.

Since the user disconnected from the app, the OAuth credentials no longer work and returns an access denied error.

I'm looking for a way to detect this error and remove the database entry containing the no longer working OAuth token in order to allow the user to properly reconnect.

I tried with the following code:

```
$result = User::model()->findByAttributes(array("oauth_uid"=>$_SESSION['scid']));
 
//If result is empty create login URL
if(empty($result)){
    $sc_auth = false;
    $scloginurl = $client->getAuthorizeUrl(array("scope"=>"non-expiring"));

//Else if result is found, try setting the access token, if access token returns errors get login URL
 }else{
 try{
  $client->setAccessToken($result['oauth_token']);
 } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e){
      $scloginurl = $client->getAuthorizeUrl(array("scope"=>"non-expiring"));
      $sc_auth = false;
      $error = 1;
 }
```

As you can see above, I tried using 'try() catch()' to see if there's any errors from setting the access token, however the website seems to return the same error and not execute any of the code in catch().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by going into the SoundCloud.php file from SoundCloud's PHP Library and replacing the code of

```
throw new Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception( .... );
```

with my code to remove the database entry and reload the window!

A little wonky since it will remove the entry regardless of exception, but it works!